# Junit4 tutorial with pure scala code samples

Tags: scala, junit4

I am at a very beginning stage of Scala Learning (I have little understanding of java code). Trying to write tiny applications and simultaneously wanting to test them. By doing this I am intending to create real life project scenario so can understand and run build mechanism, continuous testing etc.

**Where can I find JUnit4 tutorial with pure Scala code samples. Very basic samples are preferable.**

Most of my searches led me to Java based JUnit4 tutorials / books.

Kindly note that my learning environment is Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2, Scala 2.9.2 and Junit4.

Comment: If you're interested in JUnit tests, scalastyle currently uses pure junit tests, and they are pretty simple, see for example https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/scalastyle/file/FileTabCheckerTest.scala

Comment: @Matthew Farwell I am open for any alternative. Should be most advanced, feature rich, growing and should be capable to handle large scale projects. Can we rate the best among pure JUnit, Scalatest, Specs2 or anytother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend not to use JUnit4 but a Scala test framework. There are two major once:

- [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/)
- [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/)

I personally prefer the second and it integrates with JUnit, so you'll actually run the tests as JUnit tests in Eclipse but they are ScalaTest tests. See here for details: http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4_in_scala

Specs2 probably can do similar stuff, I just don't know it as well.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be a problem. Here is a tutorial: http://dearjunior.blogspot.de/2011/03/getting-started-with-junit-and-tdd-in.html.

But I recommend to use [specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/) or [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) for your tests. They have some nice features. Specs2 tests can be run in eclipse as JUnit tests by adding the @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
annotation.

Comment: Personally, I use specs2. I recommend to have a look at both and decide yourself which one is the best for you. Generally speaking, both have more features than JUnit has.

Comment: I definitely will go through the documentation of both but can you brief me major pros-cons between Scalatest and Specs2?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I'm using specs2 and never used scalatest. But they are both widely used in the community, so I guess you can't do anything wrong in choosing one of them.

Comment: I'd recommend scalatest with FunSuite. Similar to Junit, so its easy to learn, yet quite some Scala Goodness contained. See here: http://scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite